# node.js and mongodb and traceback saying Driver requires at least 2(MongoDB2.6)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Installed the latest node js and npm where node is of version `v7.8.0` and then using npm`v4.2.0` I installed the package `mongodb` locally using `npm install mongodb` got version `v3.0.5`.

Now When I try to establish connection from `node.js` to `mongodb` server using this `mongodb` package, I got traceback.

Why the latest version of node is not compatible with latest version of other packages like `mongodb` and where I can find this compatible tables if there is any :^). Thanks for you help.

Code:

```
    var mongo = require('mongodb');
    var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
    var DB_NAME = 'demodb';
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/" + DB_NAME;

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in creating DB ' + DB_NAME);
            throw err;
        }
        //var db = client.db(DB_NAME);
        console.log("Database " + DB_NAME + " created successfully!");
        db.close();
    });
```

Traceback

```
    Error in creating Database

    /home/manish/projects/practice/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:792
              throw err;
          ^
    MongoError: Server at localhost:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB2.6).
    at /home/manish/projects/practice/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:377:39
    at /home/manish/projects/practice/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:541:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding my findings here to get rid of the problems. However, I won't mind(In-fact I'll appreciate instead) if anyone defers in the answer and suggest a better one.

Searched a bit and found a module `mongodb-version-list` to list all the versions supported for the current installed `node v7.8.0` and `npm v4.2.0` I guess.

```
["3.7.3","3.7.2","3.7.1","3.6.4-rc0","3.6.3","3.6.3-rc1","3.6.3-rc0","3.6.2","3.6.2-rc0","3.6.1","3.6.1-rc1","3.6.1-rc0","3.6.0",
    "3.6.0-rc8","3.6.0-rc7","3.6.0-rc6","3.6.0-rc5","3.6.0-rc4","3.6.0-rc3","3.6.0-rc2","3.6.0-rc1","3.6.0-rc0","3.5.13","3.5.12",
    "3.5.11","3.5.10","3.5.9","3.5.8","3.5.7","3.5.6","3.5.5","3.5.4","3.5.3","3.5.2","3.5.1","3.4.14","3.4.14-rc0","3.4.13","3.4.12",
    "3.4.12-rc0","3.4.11","3.4.11-rc0","3.4.10","3.4.10-rc0","3.4.9","3.4.9-rc0","3.4.8","3.4.8-rc1","3.4.8-rc0","3.4.7","3.4.7-rc0","3.4.6",
    "3.4.6-rc0","3.4.5","3.4.5-rc4","3.4.5-rc3","3.4.5-rc2","3.4.5-rc1","3.4.5-rc0","3.4.4","3.4.4-rc0","3.4.3","3.4.3-rc2","3.4.3-rc1","3.4.2",
    "3.4.2-rc0","3.4.1","3.4.1-rc0","3.4.0","3.4.0-rc5","3.4.0-rc4","3.4.0-rc3","3.4.0-rc2","3.4.0-rc1","3.4.0-rc0","3.3.15","3.3.14","3.3.13",
    "3.3.12","3.3.11","3.3.10","3.3.9","3.3.8","3.3.7","3.3.6","3.3.5","3.3.4","3.3.3","3.3.2","3.3.1","3.3.0","3.2.19","3.2.19-rc0","3.2.18",
    "3.2.18-rc0","3.2.17","3.2.17-rc0","3.2.16","3.2.16-rc0","3.2.15","3.2.15-rc0","3.2.14","3.2.14-rc1","3.2.14-rc0","3.2.13","3.2.13-rc0",
    "3.2.12","3.2.12-rc0","3.2.11","3.2.11-rc1","3.2.11-rc0","3.2.10","3.2.10-rc2","3.2.10-rc1","3.2.10-rc0","3.2.9","3.2.9-rc1","3.2.9-rc0",
    "3.2.8","3.2.8-rc1","3.2.8-rc0","3.2.7","3.2.7-rc1","3.2.7-rc0","3.2.6","3.2.6-rc0","3.2.5","3.2.5-rc1","3.2.5-rc0","3.2.4","3.2.4-rc0","3.2.3",
    "3.2.2","3.2.2-rc2","3.2.2-rc1","3.2.2-rc0","3.2.1","3.2.1-rc3","3.2.1-rc2","3.2.1-rc1","3.2.1-rc0","3.2.0","3.2.0-rc6","3.2.0-rc5","3.2.0-rc4",
    "3.2.0-rc3","3.2.0-rc2","3.2.0-rc1","3.2.0-rc0","3.1.9","3.1.8","3.1.7","3.1.6","3.1.5","3.1.4","3.1.3","3.1.2","3.1.1","3.1.0","3.0.15",
    "3.0.15-rc0","3.0.14","3.0.13","3.0.13-rc0","3.0.12","3.0.12-rc0","3.0.11","3.0.10","3.0.10-rc1","3.0.10-rc0","3.0.9","3.0.9-rc0","3.0.8",
    "3.0.8-rc0","3.0.7","3.0.7-rc0","3.0.6","3.0.6-rc2","3.0.6-rc1","3.0.6-rc0","3.0.5","3.0.5-rc2","3.0.5-rc1","3.0.5-rc0","3.0.4","3.0.4-rc0",
    "3.0.3","3.0.3-rc2","3.0.3-rc1","3.0.3-rc0","3.0.2","3.0.2-rc0","3.0.1","3.0.1-rc0","3.0.0","3.0.0-rc9","3.0.0-rc8","3.0.0-rc7","3.0.0-rc6",
    "3.0.0-rc11","3.0.0-rc10","2.8.0-rc5","2.8.0-rc4","2.8.0-rc3","2.8.0-rc2","2.8.0-rc1","2.8.0-rc0","2.7.8","2.7.7","2.7.6","2.7.5","2.7.4","2.7.3",
    "2.7.2","2.7.1","2.7.0","2.6.12","2.6.12-rc0","2.6.11","2.6.11-rc0","2.6.10","2.6.10-rc0","2.6.9","2.6.9-rc0","2.6.8","2.6.8-rc0","2.6.7","2.6.7-rc0",
    "2.6.6","2.6.6-rc0","2.6.5","2.6.5-rc4","2.6.5-rc3","2.6.5-rc2","2.6.5-rc1","2.6.5-rc0","2.6.4","2.6.4-rc1","2.6.3","2.6.2","2.6.2-rc1","2.6.2-rc0",
    "2.6.1","2.6.1-rc1","2.6.1-rc0","2.6.0","2.6.0-rc3","2.6.0-rc2","2.6.0-rc1","2.6.0-rc0","2.5.5","2.5.4","2.5.3","2.5.2","2.5.1","2.5.0","2.4.14",
    "2.4.14-rc0","2.4.13","2.4.13-rc0","2.4.12","2.4.12-rc0","2.4.11","2.4.11-rc0","2.4.10","2.4.10-rc0","2.4.9","2.4.9-rc0","2.4.8","2.4.7",
    "2.4.7-rc0","2.4.6","2.4.6-rc1","2.4.6-rc0","2.4.5","2.4.5-rc0","2.4.4","2.4.4-rc0","2.4.3","2.4.3-rc0","2.4.2","2.4.2-rc0","2.4.1","2.4.0",
    "2.4.0-rc3","2.4.0-rc2","2.4.0-rc1","2.4.0-rc0","2.3.2","2.3.1","2.3.0","2.2.7","2.2.7-rc0","2.2.6","2.2.6-rc0","2.2.5","2.2.5-rc0","2.2.4",
    "2.2.4-rc0","2.2.3","2.2.3-rc1","2.2.3-rc0","2.2.2","2.2.2-rc1","2.2.2-rc0","2.2.1","2.2.1-rc1","2.2.1-rc0"]
```

Now coming to the `traceback` I mentioned in the post I found its the `mongodb` database server version `2.4.14` that does not seems compatible with installed `mongodb` package i.e `v3.0.5`. 
So after googled a bit and degraded the `mongodb` package version to `2.2.16` and it works just fine.